What is the body to send a complex object as a POST using Firefox devtools?
I have an object that works when I send it as JSON using Postman.
{
  nest: {
    type_id: 33,
    name: 'test'
  }
}

I want to be able to do the same thing using Firefox devtools.
When I try to post with the body below, the server receives the value as a string rather than an object. I've tried different quotes, but to no avail. Is there a format that I need to follow in order for devtools to submit my nested object correctly?



It's not clear from your question. Is 'nest=' + encodeURIComponent(  JSON.stringify( { type_id: 33, name: 'test' } ) ) what you're trying to do? If so then, nest=%7B%22type_id%22%3A33%2C%22name%22%3A%22test%22%7D. POST bodies should look like GET query strings.

The string has to be deserialized on the server. Your object is serialized into a string for transmitting via the internet because you can't send "objects". Your server then has to turn the string back into the object it represents.

{"nest": {"type_id": 33, "name": "test"}}

@Nanigashi I'm trying to send above and when I do that in postman and select it as JSON it works, but how do I do that in Firefox? I tried encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({"nest": {"type_id": 33, "name": "test"}})) which returns "%7B%22nest%22%3A%7B%22type_id%22%3A33%2C%22name%22%3A%22test%22%7D%7D" but that hasn't worked

@noassl how do I serialize it?

You could improve the question a lot by including the object ({ nest: { type_id: 33, name: 'test' } }) and the fact that your application works when you use Postman to send it as JSON.

@mangocaptain serializing to JSON is done via JSON.stringify in JavaScript. Deserialization has to happen on your server, which we don't have any information about, but you should be able to find that out by yourself by searching " parse json" or something similar using a search engine of your choice.

There are generally three formats for XMLHttpRequest POST request bodies: URI-encoded text, JSON, and multipart form data. The question about nest={"type_id":33, "name":'test'} seems to have mixed up URI-encoded text and JSON (although it is possible to combine them in a way). Multipart form data is for binaries and large transfers.
URI-encoded bodies look just like GET queries. (name1=value1&name2=value2&name3=value3 ...)
Both the names and values are URI-encoded as URI components (= and & are not), but in practice most people pick names that encode to themselves (e.g., alphanumeric).
JSON bodies are just JSON (a stringified object).
For this question, the object is ...
{
  nest: {
    type_id: 33,
    name: 'test'
  }
}

... which stringifies to {"nest":{"type_id":33,"name":"test"}}. That's the entire body.
The New Request tab of the Network Action sub-panel should have a Content-Type header with content application/json, although in the wild I see text/plain much more frequently for JSON. If there isn't a header, you can add it at the bottom where there are empty name and value fields.

For completeness, URI-encoded POSTs would (must) have a content type of application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The only values are strings, so type_id=33&name=test transmits type_id with the string value of 33.
As an aside, since JSON is a string, it would be possible to transmit URI-encoded JSON as something like
'json=' + encodeURIComponent( '{"nest":{"type_id":33,"name":"test"}}' )
which is json=%7B%22nest%22%3A%7B%22type_id%22%3A33%2C%22name%22%3A%22test%22%7D%7D, although I've never seen anyone do it.
However, rather than relying on the devtools panel to resend test POSTs, you could just use JavaScipt.
fetch( url, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: { // default is text/plain. application/x-www-form-urlencoded is another option.
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify( someObject )
} ).then( function ( response ) {
  return response.text();
} ).then( function ( responseText ) {
  // do something with responseText
} );

